# How to add tagging with autocomplete to an existing model in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, tagging, acts-as-taggable

I'm trying to add "tags" to an `Article` model in a Rails 3 application.

I'm wondering if there is a gem or plugin that has adds both the "tagging" functionality in the model and also the auto-complete helpers for the views.

I've found `acts_as_taggable` but I'm not sure if that's what I should be using. Is there something newer? I'm getting results from 2007 when I google acts_as_taggable

Comment: I implemented and tested my answer and it works great! See my updated answer with full instructions and fixes.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) work nicely together to make a SO like tagging system see example below. I don't think a suitable all in one option exists yet for rails.

**Follow these steps to get this all installed:**

1 . Backup your rails app!
 
2 . Install [jquery-rails](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails)

Note: You can install jQuery UI with `jquery-rails` but I chose not to.

3 . Download and install [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download)

Choose a theme that will compliment your web design (be sure to test the autocomplete demo with the theme you choose, the default theme did not work for me). Download the custom zip and place the `[zipfile]/js/jquery-ui-#.#.#.custom.min.js` file into your app's `/public/javascripts/` folder. place the `[zipfile]/css/custom-theme/` folder and all files into your app's `public/stylesheets/custom-theme/` folder.

4 . Add the following to your Gemfile and then run "bundle install"

> gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
>   gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'

5 . From the console run the following commands:

> rails generate acts_as_taggable_on:migration
>   rake db:migrate
>   rails generate autocomplete:install

**Make these changes in your app**

Include the necessary javascript and css files in your application layout:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom" %>  
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults, "jquery-ui-#.#.#.custom.min", "autocomplete-rails" %>
```

**Controller Example**

EDIT: Made changes based on Seth Pellegrino's comments.

```
class ArticlesController < Admin::BaseController  
  #autocomplete :tag, :name  <- Old   
  autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag' # <- New
end
```

**Model Example**

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

**Route.rb**

```
resources :articles do
  get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection    
end
```

**View Example**

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_articles_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %> 
  # note tag_list above is a virtual column created by acts_as_taggable_on
<% end %>
```

Note: This example assumes that you are only tagging one model in your entire app and you are only using the default tag type :tags. Basically the code above will search all tags and not limit them to "Article" tags.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the detailed answer. I'm going to try this and come back to update the thread :)

Comment: Everything is working except for the autocomplete, I must be missing something...

Comment: @deb - Confirm that jquery, and jquery ui, autocomplete-rails js files are included by viewing the source html. Additionally make sure the ui css file is also included. Are you using Firebug to debug with?

Comment: I figured it out, it was problem with firebug and jquery, unrelated to your code. It works great, thank you again

Comment: @deb - Great! I think this solution was more complicated that either one of use would have liked. But I think both plugins are well established and good in there own right. If I find a more elegant solution in the future I will try to post it here.

Comment: @Tim Santeford - how can you change the query if tagging is used in more locations? i.e. to search through one specific tagged field?

Comment: @TimSanteford It looks like the solution above broke when acts_as_taggable_on was [namespaced](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/commit/b90ce697f0852a1d87f64f9342c07c94d5822435). Changing the autocomplete line to explicitly specify the tag class (e.g. `autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'`)  gets everything up and running again.

Comment: @TimSanteford - if you wanted to limit the returned values to (a) a custom tag type, eg: topics and (b) limit them to "Article" tags, how do we alter the call "autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag'

Comment: @TimSanteford Hi Tim, any ideas on how to scope tags by user?

Comment: Scratch that, I figured out a way to filter by current user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244515/rails-gem-rails3-jquery-autocomplete-how-to-scope-by-user/7250426#7250426

Comment: Why is the first item "Backup your rails app"? Surely your rails app is already under version control, thus you don't need to back it up, and you have all the changes versioned?

Comment: How do I add the user id to the tags so that I am able scope?

Comment: I know this answer is a bit old, but any idea if this the rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem can work with the jquery-ui-rails gem (https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails)?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap, is there a way to customize it to use bootstrap css instead of jquery ui. currently I'm seeing a lot many js and css in app using this solution. It is working though

Answer (score 6):

The [acts_as_taggable_on_steroids](https://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids/) gem is probably your best bet. I've found that many of the tagging gems are more of a "good place to start" but then require a fair amount of customization to get the result you want.

Comment: thanks I will look at taggable on steroids. Rails gems/plugins sure have funny names

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blog post](http://cirefice.me/software%20development/select2-tag) about this recently; for the sake of brevity, my method allows you to have (optional) *context*-filtered tags (e.g. by model and by attribute on the model), whereas @Tim Santeford's solution will get you all tags for a model (not filtered by field). Below is the verbatim post.

---

I tried out [Tim Santeford's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5008263/1986871), but the problem was with the tag results. In his solution, you get *all* existing tags returned through autocomplete, and not *scoped to your models and taggable fields*! So, I came up with a solution which is in my opinion much much better; it's automatically extensible to any model you want to tag, it's efficient, and above all else it's very simple. It uses the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem and the [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) JavaScript library.

### Install the Acts-As-Taggable-On gem

1. Add acts-as-taggable-on to your Gemfile: `gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 3.5'`
2. Run `bundle install` to install it
3. Generate the necessary migrations: `rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations`
4. Run the migrations with `rake db:migrate`

Done!

### Set up normal tagging in your MVC

Let's say we have a `Film` model (because I do). Simply add the following two lines to your model:

```
class Film < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable
    acts_as_taggable_on :genres
end
```

That's it for the model. Now onto the controller. You need to accept the tag lists in your parameters. So I have the following in my `FilmsController`:

```
class FilmsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        ...
    end
    ...

    private

    def films_params
        params[:film].permit(..., :genre_list)
    end
end
```

Notice that the parameter isn't `genres` like we specified in the model. Don't ask me why, but acts-as-taggable-on expects *singular + **_list***, and this is what is required in the views.

Onto the view layer! I use the [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem and the [Slim](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim) template engine for views, so my form might look a little different than yours if you don't use the gem. But, it's just a normal **text input** field:

```
= f.input :genre_list, input_html: {value: @film.genre_list.to_s}
```

You need this `input_html` attribute with that value set in order to render it as a comma-separated string (which is what acts-as-taggable-on expects in the controller). Tagging should now work when you submit the form! If it doesn't work, I recommend watching (the amazing) [Ryan Bates' Railscast episode on tagging](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging).

### Integrating select2 into your forms

First off, we need to include the select2 library; you can either include it manually, or use (my preference) the [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) gem which packages select2 for the Rails asset pipeline.

Add the gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'select2-rails', '~> 4.0'`, then run `bundle install`.

Include the JavaScript and CSS in your asset pipeline:

In *application.js*: `//= require select2-full`. In *application.css*: `*= require select2`.

Now you need to modify your forms a bit to include what select2 expects for tagging. This can seem a bit confusing, but I'll explain everything. Change your previous form input:

```
= f.input :genre_list, input_html: {value: @film.genre_list.to_s}
```

to:

```
= f.hidden_field :genre_list, value: @film.genre_list.to_s
= f.input :genre_list,
    input_html: { id: "genre_list_select2",
                name: "genre_list_select2",
                multiple: true,
                data: { taggable: true, taggable_type: "Film", context: "genres" } },
    collection: @film.genre_list
```

We add a *hidden* input which will act as the real value sent to the controller. Select2 returns an **array**, where acts-as-taggable-on expects a **comma-separated string**. The select2 form input is converted to that string when its value changes, and set into the hidden field. We'll get to that soon.

The `id` and `name` attributes for the `f.input` actually don't matter. They just can't overlap with your `hidden` input. The `data` hash is really important here. The `taggable` field allows us to use JavaScript to initialize all select2 inputs in one go, instead of manually initializing by id for each one. The `taggable_type` field is used to filter tags for your particular model, and the `context` field is to filter on tags that have been used before in that field. Finally, the `collection` field simply sets the values appropriately in the input.

The next part is JavaScript. We need to initialize all select2 elements throughout the application. To do this, I simply added the following function to my `application.js` file, so that it works for every route:

```
// Initialize all acts-as-taggable-on + select2 tag inputs
$("*[data-taggable='true']").each(function() {
    console.log("Taggable: " + $(this).attr('id') + "; initializing select2");
    $(this).select2({
        tags: true,
        theme: "bootstrap",
        width: "100%",
        tokenSeparators: [','],
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        ajax: {
            url: "/tags",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 100,
            data: function (params) {
                console.log("Using AJAX to get tags...");
                console.log("Tag name: " + params.term);
                console.log("Existing tags: " + $(this).val());
                console.log("Taggable type: " + $(this).data("taggable-type"));
                console.log("Tag context: " + $(this).data("context"));
                return {
                    name: params.term,
                    tags_chosen: $(this).val(),
                    taggable_type: $(this).data("taggable-type"),
                    context: $(this).data("context"),
                    page: params.page
                }
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                console.log("Got tags from AJAX: " + JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
                params.page = params.page || 1;

                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.name,
                            // id has to be the tag name, because acts_as_taggable expects it!
                            id: item.name
                        }
                    })
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
});
```

This may look complex, but it's not too difficult. Basically, the `$("*[data-taggable='true']")` selector just gets every HTML element where we have `taggable: true` set in the data. We just added that to the form, and this is why - we want to be able to initialize select2 for all *taggable* fields.

The rest is just AJAX-related code. Essentially, we make an AJAX call to `/tags` with the parameters `name`, `taggable_type` and `context`. Sound familiar? Those are the data attributes that we set in our form input. When the results are returned, we simply give select2 the name of the tag.

Now you're probably thinking: *I dont have a `/tags` route!*. You're right! But you're about to :)

### Adding the /tags route

Go into your `routes.rb` file and add the following: `resources :tags`. You don't have to add *all* the routes for tags, but I did so that I could have an easy way to CRUD tags. You could also simply do: `get '/tags' => 'tags#index'`

That's really the only route we *need* at the moment. Now that we have the route, we have to create a controller called `TagsController`:

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag
                .where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{params[:name]}%")
                .where.not(name: params[:tags_chosen])
                .includes(:taggings)
                .where(taggings: {taggable_type: params[:taggable_type]})
        @tags = @tags.where(taggings: {context: params[:context] }) if params[:context]
        @tags.order!(name: :asc)
        render json: @tags
    end
end
```

This is fairly simple. We can send a request to `/tags`, with the parameters `name` (the tag text), `tags_chosen` (the existing selected tags), `taggable_type` (the *model* that is tagged), and optional `context` (the *field* that is tagged). If we have genre tags for "comedy" and "conspiracy", then type *co* in our form, the JSON rendered should look something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "comedy",
        "taggings_count": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "conspiracy",
        "taggings_count": 1
    }
]
```

Now in the select2 input, you should see "comedy" and "conspiracy" as auto-completed tag options!

### My tags won't save!

There's one last step. We need to set the select2 values into our `hidden` field that we created earlier.

This code may be different for you depending on how you structure your form, but you essentially want to get the select2 input, convert the array of strings to a CSV string (e.g. `["comedy", "conspiracy"]` --> `"comedy, conspiracy"`), and set that CSV string into the hidden field. That's not too difficult, fortunately.

You can catch the select2 input changed event, or anything else that suits you. It's your choice, but this step must be done to ensure that the Rails controller receives the value correctly. Again, in *application.js*:

```
/*
* When any taggable input changes, get the value from the select2 input and
* convert it to a comma-separated string. Assign this value to the nearest hidden
* input, which is the input for the acts-on-taggable field. Select2 submits an array,
* but acts-as-taggable-on expects a CSV string; it is why this conversion exists.
*/
$(document).on('select2:select select2:unselect', "*[data-taggable='true']", function() {

    var taggable_id = $(this).attr('id')
    // genre_list_select2 --> genre_list
    var hidden_id = taggable_id.replace("_select2", "");
    // film_*genre_list* ($= jQuery selectors ends with)
    var hidden = $("[id$=" + hidden_id + "]")
    // Select2 either has elements selected or it doesn't, in which case use []
    var joined = ($(this).val() || []).join(",");
    hidden.val(joined);
});
```

You should see the following in your controller action once you have successfully converted your values: `"genre_list"=>"comedy,conspiracy"`

And that's all you need to do autocomplete tags in Rails using acts-as-taggable-on and select2!

Comment: Very interesting I am trying to get it to work, but the tags controller throws syntax errors: "unexpected '.', expecting kEND .where". Why does that happen? Tagging works, but autocomplete not yet! When compacting it on one line I get: "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"

Comment: @SEJU You probably actually have a syntax error. Can you post your code on Pastebin or something and link it?

Comment: I put it on https://pastebin.com/6tnWqHVy. Since tagging works, but autocomplete does not, I suspect the Tags Controller might be the problem.

Comment: @SEJU Since you're on Rails 3, it looks like you can't use `.where.not` for negative queries... you'll have to change it a bit like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7391874/1986871). Play around with that particular syntax... I've never used Rails 3 so I don't know of a precise example for how to change it, but you'll have to change the `.where.not` clause for sure! And if you like my answer, give me a +1 ;)

Comment: How about: ".where(:name != params[:tags_chosen])", this way the page loads, but I get an invalide MySQL statement. https://pastebin.com/deCW0FsL

Comment: @SEJU Yeah I don't think you can use `!=` in Rails that way, at least not in Rails 3. You'll have to figure this one out for yourself by searching StackOverflow and other sources. Since I have never used Rails 3 I don't know the correct query syntax for a negation like that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184533/discussion-between-seju-and-chris-cirefice).