# Exclude active record entries based on another active record attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, join, activerecord

(feel free to change the headline to what may be more suitable)

I am using Ruby on Rails and I have two model sets:

- Page
- Store
- A page `has_many` stores.
- A store has the attribute `status_nbr` which ranges from 1-5.

For example, page #1 could have 5 stores where two of them have `status_nbr = 1` and three of them have `status_nbr = 3`.

I want to run a query which to find all Pages where there is **no** store who has status_nbr = 1. In other words, Pages that lack stores with status_nbr = 1. How do I do that? I assume this can be done with some clever join?

As for now I run a loop:

```
ok_list = []
Page.all.each do |page|
  ok_list << page.id unless page.stores.where(:status_nbr => 1).blank?
end
@pages = Page.where(:id => ok)
```

which is very bad/slow programming.

Edit: This is not a duplicate question of the one referred. My model is dependent on another model and the attribute of that other model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Model find where not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426421/rails-model-find-where-not-equal)

Comment: The (important) difference here is that this has to do with another model as well. The question you refer to is if the attribute is in the same model!

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

`Page.joins(:store).where.not(store: { status_nbr: 1}).uniq`

Comment: This answer does not work, for the same reason as the first one (which is now removed). First of all it would need a .distinct in order to receive unique Pages. Nonetheless, it still shows Pages with stores with status_nbr = 1. I have confirmed by looping the results of this and check for stores with status_nbr == 1.

Comment: I have made and edit, also are these values stored as integers or strings?

Comment: This should at least be Page.joins(:stores).where.not(stores: { status_nbr: 1}).uniq and although it is elegant it doesn't work. If I do Page.joins(:stores).where.not(stores: { status_nbr: 1}).uniq.each do |page| puts page.stores.where(:status_nbr => 1).count end it still shows Pages where at least some stores have status_nbr = 1. So, thanks, but unfortunately this doesnt work. My suspicion is that there is a need for another type of join but I don't know.