# Acts_as_taggable_on + autocomplete with more than one tag category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm going through the following answer to add autocomplete for tags on my app

[How to add tagging with autocomplete to an existing model in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937185/how-to-add-tagging-with-autocomplete-to-an-existing-model-in-rails)

But I am looking to have different types of tags, ie. skills and interests.

I'd like to agregate more than one tag type, or is there a way to add a tag type to acts_as_taggable_on?