# Making rails3-jquery-autocomplete work with these Post and Tag models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a *Post* and a *Tag* model (the later as an attribute called `:name`).

They are associated with `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

**views/posts/_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= f.label :tags %>
<%= autocomplete_field_tag :tags, params[:tags], autocomplete_tags_name_posts_path %>
```

**routes.rb:**

```
  resources :posts do
    get :autocomplete_tags_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  autocomplete :tags, :name
```

Nothing happens and there are no errors.

I'm a bit confused about whether using `:tags` or `:tags_name`. As shown in the [documentation](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete).

(they both produce errors about undefined methods and variables)

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you, works with **act_as_taggable** but it's the same idea.

[How to add tagging with autocomplete to an existing model in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937185/how-to-add-tagging-with-autocomplete-to-an-existing-model-in-rails)