# Rails: Couldn't find Post with 'id'=autocomplete_tag_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

Using [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) and [rails4-autocomplete](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) to autocomplete tags. Here is my code.

*routes.rb*

```
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag

  resources :posts do
    get :autocomplete_tag_name, :on => :collection
  end
```

*posts_controller.rb*

```
autocomplete :tag, :name
```

*application.js*

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

*_form.html.haml*

```
= f.input :tag_list, :url => autocomplete_tag_name_posts_path, :as => :autocomplete
```

When I start typing, I can see the request to the server but return (404) Not Found as

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/autocomplete_tag_name?term=rails
```

Firefox DevTool Network

````
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /posts/autocomplete_tag_name
============================================================

> Couldn't find Post with 'id'=autocomplete_tag_name

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb, line 133
---------------------------------------------

``` ruby
  128     end
  129   
  130     private
  131       # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  132       def set_post
> 133         @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  134       end
  135   
  136       # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  137       def post_params
  138         params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image, :tag_list)
````

It couldn't find a post with id `autocomplete_tag_name` which it shouldn't be like this.

If I hard coded the request to

```
http://localhost:3000/tags/autocomplete_tag_name?term=rails
```

It returns 200 (ok)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a routing error. Looking at the hard coded link, it is working at `localhost:3000/tags/`, but your 404 error is looking for `localhost:3000/posts/`. Have a look at the answer on this post, its for Rails3 but it may be of some use: [How to add tagging with autocomplete to an existing model in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937185/how-to-add-tagging-with-autocomplete-to-an-existing-model-in-rails)

Comment: Yes. I tried that answer and it's still the same considering the diff in Rails 4 changes.